# Display JSON, XML, CSV data in Fusioncharts and pure JAVASCRIPT example

Tags: javascript, json, xml, csv, fusioncharts

There is a vendor example for charting data from JSON or XML:
[fusion charts](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/plain-javascript/setting-data-source-using-url)

I'm a total beginner and can not make that works properly, so having 2 questions:

1. Could you please post me a COMPLETE HTML page source with JScript embedded properly showing the JSON and XML data example while it's missing on the samples page?
2. Could someone alter that mentioned/complete HTML webpage for showing CSV data from a similar file?

Cheers.

btw - datas:

**--- CSV ---**

```
Polska, Saudi, Kanada, Iran, Russia, UAE, US, China

290,    260,    180,    140,    115,    100, 30, 30
```

--- cat remote.json ---

```
{
    // Chart Configuration
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Wykres danych z pliku JSON",
        "subCaption": "In MMbbl = One Million barrels",
        "xAxisName": "Country",
        "yAxisName": "Reserves (MMbbl)",
        "numberSuffix": "K",
        "theme": "fusion",
    },
    // Chart Data
    "data": [{
        "label": "Polska",
        "value": "290"
    }, {
        "label": "Saudi",
        "value": "260"
    }, {
        "label": "Kanada",
        "value": "180"
    }, {
        "label": "Iran",
        "value": "140"
    }, {
        "label": "Russia",
        "value": "115"
    }, {
        "label": "UAE",
        "value": "100"
    }, {
        "label": "US",
        "value": "30"
    }, {
        "label": "China",
        "value": "30"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got working example by this workaround, but it's NOT the method that was proposed by the vendor/authors of tutorial, so despite the following the question still remains, how to run the exact tutorial approach and also how to draw it from CSV

working IDEA:

with JSON

```
{
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Wykres danych z pliku JSON",
        "subCaption": "Jakiś bardzo szczegółowy opis tych danych...",
        "xAxisName": "Kraj",
        "yAxisName": "Mierzona wartość z pliku JSON",
        "numberSuffix": "K",
        "theme": "fusion"
    },
    "data": [{
        "label": "Polska",
        "value": "290"
    }, {
        "label": "Saudi",
        "value": "260"
    }, {
        "label": "Kanada",
        "value": "180"
    }, {
        "label": "Iran",
        "value": "140"
    }, {
        "label": "Russia",
        "value": "115"
    }, {
        "label": "UAE",
        "value": "100"
    }, {
        "label": "US",
        "value": "130"
    }, {
        "label": "China",
        "value": "80"
    }]
}
```

and HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Przykład wykresu dla mnie</title>
<!-- Include fusioncharts core library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<!-- Include fusion theme -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // TO JEST PIERWSZY WYKRES i ŁADOWANIE DANYCH z INNEGO pliku JSON:
    const chartConfig = {
    type: 'column3d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '80%',
    height: '450',
    dataFormat: 'jsonurl',
    dataSource: 'wykresy4remote.json'
    };
    FusionCharts.ready(function(){
    var fusioncharts = new FusionCharts(chartConfig);
    fusioncharts.render();
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Please advise, how to do it better and also with CSV.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Render a chart and upon click of a button alert the chart's data in
// CSV format.
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var chart = new FusionCharts({
        type: "column2d",
        renderAt: "chart-container",
        dataSource: "weekly-sales.json",
        dataFormat: "jsonurl"
    }).render();

    // Assign the functionality of retrieving and alerting CSV data to
    // click event of a button
    document.getElementById("alert-csv-data").onclick = function () {
        alert(chart.getChartData("csv"));
    };
});
```

Here is the demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/L486ydop/

To know more about this feature please refer in this document define all methods - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods

Refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusioncharts-aspnet-visualization/data-engine/data-engine-api#csv-file